# I seem to be losing CSS code in our footer on some pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wpbakery

If I go to the pages below and look at the footer the links in the right column are purple buttons:

```
https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/
https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/are-you-safe/
https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/trusted-resources/
```

Great! Just what we want.

But if I go to some of the other pages they are now just links with no button behind them:

```
https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/blog/
https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/tales-from-the-divorceside/ (forum page)
https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/resource-category/fitness-personal-style/
https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/resource/arizona-luxury-art-club/
```

We are using WordPress 5.2.1.

I have checked the code and can't seem to find any pattern to why these specific pages are breaking. The CSS code comes from the WPBakery plugin which came with our theme. It may be because of their templates (the first pages are set to default templates and the other pages are set to be the blog, bbpress and are using the theme templates) but I don't think the footer code is any different for them.

There should be buttons where the links are on the second list of links.

Comment: Hi @Matt, your resulting CSS files are not the same in both sets of pages (decompressed working has 107882 lines, non-working one has 89599 lines ). First set of pages have css containing `.vc_general.vc_btn3`, the second sets does not. This could be an issue around minification.

Comment: Looks like the CSS files are different via minification on each page: https://imgur.com/a/tZAmNKg

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that the pages that don't display the buttons correctly are not loading the style file: https://dev.shiftdivorceguide.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css

I would see how to load it in them if you know how, or alternatively even though you are repeating code, you could add the buttons styles to the Custom CSS section in Customizer and be done with it. The CSS you need to add is probably

```
.vc_btn3.vc_btn3-color-violet, .vc_btn3.vc_btn3-color-violet.vc_btn3-style-flat {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #8d6dc4;
    }
    .vc_btn3.vc_btn3-shape-rounded {
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

.vc_general.vc_btn3 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```